# How to correctly create an extended Pydantic model

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, pydantic

I am working on a app which uses FastAPI and ElasticSearch. I thought it is a good idea to use Pydantic models with some abstractions to create entity classes, so that it becomes inter-operable in the API and Index layers. When I tried extending a base entity class (which is a Pydantic BaseModel), the new objects I create is not initializing correctly and failing validations. What is the correct way to do this ?

For example, I created the following class hierarchy

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
from datetime import datetime
from pydantic import BaseModel, field_serializer, field_validator

class BaseIndex(BaseModel, metaclass=ABCMeta):
    id: str
    name: str
    created_on: datetime
    modified_on: datetime
    created_by: str
    modified_by: str

    @field_serializer("created_on", "modified_on", mode="plain")
    @classmethod
    def serialize_datetime(cls, v: datetime):
        return int(v.timestamp())

    @field_validator("created_on", "modified_on", mode="after")
    @classmethod
    def validate_datetime(cls, v: int):
        return datetime.utcfromtimestamp(v)

    @abstractmethod
    def as_schema(self, with_defaults: bool = False):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def from_record(cls, record: dict[str, Any]):
        pass
# ----------------------------------------------------------- #
class UserIndex(BaseIndex):
    user_name: str
    email: str
    first_name: str
    last_name: str
    groups: list[str]
    roles: list[str]
    last_login: datetime

    @field_serializer("last_login", mode="plain")
    def serialize_last_login(cls, value: datetime):
        return int(value.timestamp())

    @field_validator("last_login", mode="after")
    def validate_last_login(cls, value: int):
        return datetime.utcfromtimestamp(value)

    def as_schema(self, with_defaults: bool = False):
        return {
            "properties": {
                "id": {"type": "keyword"},
                "name": {"type": "string"},
                "user_name": {"type": "keyword"},
                "email": {"type": "keyword"},
                "first_name": {"type": "string", "copy_to": "name"},
                "last_name": {"type": "string", "copy_to": "name"},
                "groups": {"type": "string"},
                "roles": {"type": "string"}
            },

        }
```

When I create a User object with the details , providing values of everything like

```
user = UserIndex(id="u1", name="A1", user_name="Bob", email="bob@bb.com", first_name="Bob", last_name="B", 
            groups=["g1", "g2"], roles=["r1", "r2"], last_login=datetime.now())
```

ends up as validation error

```
File ".....\Lib\site-packages\pydantic\main.py", line 150, in __init__
    __pydantic_self__.__pydantic_validator__.validate_python(data, self_instance=__pydantic_self__)
pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 4 validation errors for User
created_on
  Field required [type=missing, input_value={'id': 'u1..': 'A1'}, input_type=dict]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.1.2/v/missing
modified_on
  Field required [type=missing, input_value={'id': 'u1..': 'A1'}, input_type=dict]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.1.2/v/missing
created_by
  Field required [type=missing, input_value={'id': 'u1..': 'A1'}, input_type=dict]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.1.2/v/missing
modified_by
  Field required [type=missing, input_value={'id': 'u1..': 'A1'}, input_type=dict]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.1.2/v/missing
```

Any one can point me in the right direction ? Is this a possibility in pydantic ? I could not see any examples in the official docs though.

Comment: I would be hesitant to use another metaclass since I'm pretty sure pedantic BaseModel relies on it's own metaclass, but I don't know if that is the cause of your problem here

Comment: Note, in your example, `UserIndex` doesn't inherit from `BaseIndex`. And there is no `User`. You really must provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you show your User class? I only see UserIndex and UserIndex has no parent

Comment: if you are treating `UserIndex` as a mixin to your `User` pydantic model then it probably needs to inherit from `BaseModel` too

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for pointing out that. I was trying to mask the original code here. Updated with the right one.

Comment: @Anentropic - It was a typo in my example. Corrected it now.

Comment: I suspect these problems are not related to extending the base model but to how the default values are provided. e.g. `@field_validator("created_on", "modified_on", mode="after")` I think this should maybe be `mode="before"` so it can provide a default value before the required validation takes place. And `created_by` and `modified_by` need a similar validator.

Comment: @Anentropic is correct in that this is simply due to the fact that you have missing values for **required** fields. However writing a `before` validator will not save you in Pydantic v2. Either a field has a default and is thus _not required_ or it has no default and _is required_. Your `created_`/`modified_` fields are all required. It is as simple as that.